# Test git connection with libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm using libgit2sharp and I'd like to be able to test the connection to a specific repository providing its URL and a username/password. So far, I've only been able to do this by cloning the repository but I don't want the files to be retrieved, I just want to see if the information provided can be used to connect to the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you only want to test the connectivity, I believe the quickest way would be to use the static `Repository.ListRemoteReferences()` method.

This will retrieve the list of known references from the remote repositories, leveraging the whole network stack.

An override allows you to pass in your credentials (for private repositories, for instance).

Comment: Okay, that works. I tried that but I quit because of the error "The remote never connected". I thought it was because of the fact that the repo was not cloned but the user I was using was actually not correct. Thanks